# how to delete lines connected with "+" signs with sed

Tags: sed

In this example, "+" sign means it connects the previous line and the current line. So I like to delete a specific group of lines that are connected by "+". 
For example, I'd like to remove from 1st line to 4th line(.groupA ~ + G H I). Please help me on how to do it with sed.

[image]

Comment: In wich language?

Comment: You should type the example instead of using an image. You also need to type the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete lines starting with `.groupA` and all consecutive `+`-prefixed lines, one easy to understand approach is:

```
sed '/\.groupA/,/^[^+]/ { /\.groupA/d; /\.groupA/!{/^\+/d} }' file
```

We first select everything between `.groupA` and the first non `+`-prefixed line (inclusive), then for that selection of lines, we delete the first line (containing `.groupA`), and of the remaining lines, we delete all with `+` prefix.

Note you need to escape regex metacharacters (like `.` and `+`) if you want to match them literally.

---

A little bit more advanced, but **more elegant** (only one use of starting block pattern) approach uses a loop to skip the first line of the matched block, and all the following lines that start with `+`:

```
sed -n '/\.groupA/ { :a; n; s/^\+//; ta }; p' file
```

Comment: Thanks randomir~~ I'll try it with my linux machine at work tomorrow~~

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works very well. Thanks a lot for your advice~~

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is more readily done with `awk`, but kindly just ignore if that is not an option for you.

So, every time I see a line starting with `.groupA`, I set a flag `d` to say I am deleting, and then skip to the next line. If I see a line starting with a `+` and I am currently deleting, I skip to the next line. If I see anything else, I change the flag to say I am no longer deleting and print the line:

```
awk '/^\.groupA/  {d=1; next}
     /^+/ && d==1 {next} 
                  {d=0; print}' file
```

**Sample Output**

```
** Example **
abcdef ghijkl
.groupB abc def
+ JKL
+ MNO
+ GHI
opqrst vwxyz
```

---

You can cast it as a one-liner like this:

```
awk '/^\.groupA/{d=1; next} d==1 && /^+/ {next} {d=0;print}' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, you are right I shall try and absorb that into my brain, but it's already overflowing ;-) Maybe you can think of my `d` as meaning *"definitelyInBlock"* :-)

Comment: Thanks Mark~ I'll try it with awk based on your suggestion as well.